# JS Fiddle OnLoad

Tags: jsfiddle

My code is working in JS Fiddle but the same code is not running in Dreamweaver.
I have tried using `window.onload()` function but still not helping. The issue is with the onLoad type in JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of your JS library in Dreamweaver,if it is working properly in fiddle then it is supposed to work properly in Dreamweaver.There is the possibility that your code is not getting javascript library path properly.